# Terminology for CubeSat telecommunications

Tags: communication, terminology

I'm looking at a [brochure for the Iris V2 Deep Space Transponder by JPL](https://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov/files/dsn/Brochure_IrisV2_201507.pdf). At the end of the brochure there is some data on suggested antennas. For each antenna the bps at approximately 1 AU is shown for opposition, arrive, and conjunction.

What do opposition, arrive, and conjunction mean with respect to telecommunications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conjunction and opposition are terms used in positional astronomy, see the Wikipedia article [Opposition (planets)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposition_(planets)) for an illustration.

I think what we've got in the brochure you refer to is an example of poor presentation design.  I *believe* the expression `Mars ~1 AU (bps)` in the 3-column heading of the tables you are referring to is supposed to be associated with the "arrive" column, i.e., the data rate is for "arrival at Mars when the distance to Earth is approximately 1 AU."  This would be consistent with the other two columns where the data rates are higher at opposition (Mars less than 1 AU distant) and significantly lower at opposition where Mars is about 2.5 AU away.  (The distances vary, as illustrated at [How Far is Mars from Earth?](https://www.universetoday.com/14824/distance-from-earth-to-mars/))

I will have to write to Courtney Duncan to ensure my interpretation is correct.  Once I get a response, I will update this answer.

---

**UPDATE**

---

Date: Wed, 02 Aug 2017 03:53:03 -0400
From: Fred Koschara 
To: Courtney Duncan 
Subject: Puzzling specs in Iris V2 CubeSat Deep Space Transponder data sheet

> Hello Courtney --
>
> I happened to look at the Iris V2 CubeSat Deep Space Transponder data
>   sheet
>   (https://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov/files/dsn/Brochure_IrisV2_201507.pdf)
>   and found the data rate tables on page 4 rather puzzling.  After
>   pondering the matter for a while, I came to the conclusion that the
>   expression "Mars ~1 AU (bps)" in the 3-column heading of the tables on
>   that page is supposed to be associated with the "Arrive" column, i.e.,
>   the data rate shown is for "arrival at Mars when the distance to Earth
>   is approximately 1 AU."  This would be consistent with the other two
>   columns where the data rates are higher at opposition (Mars less than
>   1 AU distant) and significantly lower at opposition where Mars is
>   about 2.5 AU away.
>
> Is this interpretation correct?
>
> Thank you for your time and information.
>
> -- Fred Koschara, President
>     The L5 Development Group

---

Date: Thu, 3 Aug 2017 02:49:00 +0000
From: "Duncan, Courtney B (337G)" 
To: Fred Koschara 
Subject: Re: Puzzling specs in Iris V2 CubeSat Deep Space Transponder data sheet

> Hi Fred,
>
> Yes, that's correct.  1 A.U. is a nominal distance for a Mars arrival
>   (or departure) from (to) earth which is a likely time for things to be
>   happening with SmallSat payloads.
>
> And at opposition, it's about half an AU (in round numbers, average is
>   0.524), and at conjunction 2.5 (2.524).
>
> It just so happens that Mars is just leaving conjunction right now. 
>   We usually stand down missions for a couple of weeks in order to avoid
>   communications issues that can occur due to lots of sun noise in this
>   period.
>
> That table is further confused by the fact that all data rates were
>   rounded down to the next DSN supported data rate and so are, on
>   average, root two pessimistic.  DSN data rates go up and down from
>   1000 bits per second in factors of two.
>
> Courtney
>
> Courtney Duncan
>  Supervisor, Reprogrammable Signal Processing Group
>   337G
>  Flight Communications Systems Section
>  M/S 161-260
>  Jet
>   Propulsion Laboratory, California Institute of Technology
>  4800 Oak
>   Grove
>  Pasadena, CA 91109